# How to apply a function to a quartile subset?

Tags: r

I have a data set that tracks sales (logmove) for certain customer characteristics and am trying to find the quartile ranges for a certain characteristic (income). I have created the quartile ranges of INCOME but I need to find the average of sales for each quartile, which I cannot figure out.

code so far

```
oj = read.csv("oj.csv")
dom = (subset(oj, brand == "dominicks"))
summary(dom$INCOME)

applyQuant = function(x){
  cut(x, breaks = c(quantile(dom$INCOME, probs = seq(0,1, by = 0.25))), 
      labels = c("Q1", "Q2", "Q3", "Q4"), include.lowest = TRUE)
}
dom.quant = sapply(dom$INCOME, applyQuant)
```

Basically I need to have four groups of incomes (x-variable) based on quartiles then find the average sales (y value) for each quantile range.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply assign the quantile result as a new column. Then run `ave` or `aggregate` for average sales.

```
dom$quant <- sapply(dom$INCOME, applyQuant)
```

In fact, `cut` does not require a loop such as `sapply` so assign column directly:

```
dom$quant <- cut(dom$INCOME, 
                 breaks = c(quantile(dom$INCOME, probs = seq(0,1, by = 0.25))), 
                 labels = c("Q1", "Q2", "Q3", "Q4"), include.lowest = TRUE)

# NEW COLUMN AGGREGATION
dom$quant_sales_mean <- with(dom, ave(SALES, quant, FUN=mean))
dom

# NEW DATA FRAME AGGREGATION
agg_df <- aggregate(SALES ~ quant, dom, mean)
agg_df
```